# Warning message in capsule.bxb

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I have created a sample bixby capsule and it was working fine till last week. I have opened the capsule today to find a warning message in my capsule.bxb file and my capsule stopped working.

Here is the warning message : WARN_DEPRECATED Add 'support-halt-effect-in-computed-inputs' to 'runtime-flags' and adjust to new behaviour: encountered halt effects during computed inputs will halt.

Below is the code in capsule.bxb file

```
capsule{  
  id (vobo.roqos_support)
  version (0.1.0)
  format (3)
  targets {
    target (bixby-mobile-en-US)
  }  
  marketplace-constraints {    
    country-constraints {
      allowed-list {
        allow (US)
        allow (CA)
      }
    }    
    device-model-constraints {
      allowed-list {
        allow (SM-G965N)    // S9+ Korean version
        allow (SM-G960[A-Z]?)  // any variant of S9
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a known issue that is currently being addressed. In my experience, this warning shouldn't stop a capsule from running. Do you get any specific error?

Answer (score 1):

The warning will go away if you add this to your `capsule.bxb` file.

```
  runtime-flags {
    support-halt-effect-in-computed-inputs
  }
```

As for the "capsule stopped working", please update your question to provide more details on what that means.